Hide Chat Button in Messaging Web not working
Anyone had luck with implementing their own Chat Button launching for Messaging?
Following their API document I've set:
embeddedservice_bootstrap.settings.hideChatButtonOnLoad = true;

However, the button still shows when I hit the init method and load it. I don't see any other documentation on how to hide this button.

Did you confirm that you are not using the show button API? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/service/messaging-web/references/m4w-reference/settingsAPI.html#:~:text=If%20you%20use%20showChatButton%20API%2C%20the%20API%20overrides%20the%20hideChatButtonOnLoad%20setting.

Confirmed, that I am not using the show button API. This happens on the initial load which the documentation state should hide the button. The show API looks to handle when you want to force show (or hide) the button.
